# Scraping a PowerBI dashboard report: expanding rows and loading/saving values in a scrolling table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

### Objective:

I'm trying to scrape a PowerBI report for "Reported deliveries >> By number of vaccines" in the [the "Delivery" page on this public PowerBI dashboard](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNmE0YjZiNzUtZjk2OS00ZTg4LThlMzMtNTRhNzE0NzA4YmZlIiwidCI6Ijc3NDEwMTk1LTE0ZTEtNGZiOC05MDRiLWFiMTg5MjAyMzY2NyIsImMiOjh9&pageName=ReportSectiona329b3eafd86059a947b) using Selenium to get table listing all countries, with the name of the vaccines delivered, and the number of doses delivered.

### Target and setup:

[image: Selecting the view, expanding the rows]

This screencap shows the PowerBI report that I'm trying to scrape. After clicking on "Delivery" on the landing page and selecting "Reported deliveries >> By number of vaccines", there is a table that loads up on the bottom half of the page as you can see in this image. You can right-click anywhere on the table to expand all the rows, which are country names. Beneath each country name, is the name of the vaccine delivered in one column, and the  "Doses delivered" in the adjacent column. There are 100+ rows with country names, and these load dynamically as you scroll down through this table.

### Progress so far:

I've managed to start a Chrome headless browser, get to the "Delivery" page by clicking on the relevant button, and then open the correct report that I want by clicking on the relevant tick box in the "View option" menu on the left. After this I'm stuck.  I can't figure out how to expand all of the rows in this dynamically rendered table, and I also can't figure out how to scroll down through the table and save the country names, along with their respective vaccine names and number of doses delivered.

With regards to expanding all of the Country name rows, I've seen a few posts here in StackOverflow suggesting the use of Selenium's Context Click in the Actions class, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it to my example.

With regards to the scrolling problem, I'm at a bit of a loss here as well. I tried, in vain, to find the underlying API where data was being called for the table, but my very novice eyes were not able to spot anything, and I'm wondering how else to scroll all the way down the table to scrape this data.

Any help, hints, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

### Code up to now

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

webdriver = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe"
options = ChromeOptions()
driver = Chrome(webdriver, options = options)

url = 'https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNmE0YjZiNzUtZjk2OS00ZTg4LThlMzMtNTRhNzE0NzA4YmZlIiwidCI6Ijc3NDEwMTk1LTE0ZTEtNGZiOC05MDRiLWFiMTg5MjAyMzY2NyIsImMiOjh9&pageName=ReportSectiona329b3eafd86059a947b'

driver.get(url)
  
#click on "Delivery" button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pvExplorationHost"]/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[11]/transform').click()

#click on "Reported deliveries >> By number of vaccines" click box
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pvExplorationHost"]/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[8]/transform/div/div[3]/div/visual-modern/div/button').click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Update: I found a way to scrape all the data from the table. What I found works, is to scrape 11 elements at a time, locate the scrollbar element and click just below it. The code is a little rough. Right now I am just iterating 70 times through the `grab 11 elements` => `click on scrollbar` workflow, which gets you.... most of the way through the table. I used the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

webdriver = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe"
options = ChromeOptions()
driver = Chrome(webdriver, options = options)

def wait_for_element(selector_type, selector):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((selector_type, selector)))

url = 'https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNmE0YjZiNzUtZjk2OS00ZTg4LThlMzMtNTRhNzE0NzA4YmZlIiwidCI6Ijc3NDEwMTk1LTE0ZTEtNGZiOC05MDRiLWFiMTg5MjAyMzY2NyIsImMiOjh9&pageName=ReportSectiona329b3eafd86059a947b'

driver.get(url)
wait_for_element(By.XPATH, '//visual-container-modern[11]//button').click()
wait_for_element(By.XPATH, '//visual-container-modern[8]//button').click()
table_element = wait_for_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.expandableContent.pivotTableCellWrap')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.context_click(table_element)
action.perform()
wait_for_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[title="Expand"]').click()
wait_for_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[title="All"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
for x in range(70):
    first_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.expandableContent.pivotTableCellWrap')
    second_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.pivotTableCellWrap.cell-interactive.tablixAlignRight')
    for i in range(11):
        print(first_column[i].text + ': ' + second_column[i].text)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.scroll-bar-part-bar')[1], 0, 55)
    actions.click()
    actions.perform()
```

and the output is like this:

```
China: 275,338,000.00
 : 275,338,000.00
USA: 264,505,725.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 134,063,475.00
Moderna: 112,801,100.00
Janssen: 17,641,150.00
India: 154,211,511.00
 : 154,211,511.00
Indonesia: 60,000,000.00
Sinovac: 60,000,000.00
Brazil: 44,100,000.00
Sinovac: 275,338,000.00
AstraZeneca: 275,338,000.00
Germany: 264,505,725.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 134,063,475.00
AstraZeneca: 112,801,100.00
Moderna: 17,641,150.00
Spain: 154,211,511.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 154,211,511.00
AstraZeneca: 60,000,000.00
Moderna: 60,000,000.00
Janssen: 44,100,000.00
Italy: 6,563,100.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 146,400.00
AstraZeneca: 23,705,865.00
Moderna: 16,352,485.00
Janssen: 5,277,380.00
France: 1,896,200.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 179,800.00
AstraZeneca: 23,351,295.00
Moderna: 15,253,095.00
Janssen: 5,407,600.00
Turkey: 2,484,200.00
 : 6,563,100.00
Mexico: 146,400.00
AstraZeneca: 23,705,865.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 16,352,485.00
CanSino Biologicals: 5,277,380.00
Sinovac: 1,896,200.00
Gamaleya Research Institute: 179,800.00
Russia: 23,351,295.00
 : 15,253,095.00
Chile: 5,407,600.00
 : 2,484,200.00
 : 20,070,743.00
Poland: 20,070,743.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 14,848,435.00
AstraZeneca: 14,848,435.00
Moderna: 13,825,476.00
Janssen: 13,825,476.00
UAE: 11,879,200.00
 : 7,815,600.00
Israel: 2,695,200.00
 : 1,250,800.00
Saudi Arabia: 117,600.00
 : 20,070,743.00
Morocco: 20,070,743.00
 : 14,848,435.00
Bangladesh: 14,848,435.00
AstraZeneca: 13,825,476.00
Argentina: 13,825,476.00
Gamaleya Research Institute: 11,879,200.00
Beijing Institute of Biological Products (CNBG): 7,815,600.00
AstraZeneca: 2,695,200.00
Netherlands: 1,250,800.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 117,600.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 9,100,000.00
AstraZeneca: 8,000,245.00
Moderna: 5,420,245.00
Janssen: 2,000,000.00
Romania: 580,000.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 7,112,110.00
AstraZeneca: 4,463,550.00
Moderna: 1,852,960.00
Hungary: 716,400.00
 : 79,200.00
Colombia: 6,365,530.00
 : 9,100,000.00
Portugal: 8,000,245.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 5,420,245.00
AstraZeneca: 2,000,000.00
Moderna: 580,000.00
Philippines: 7,112,110.00
Sinovac: 4,463,550.00
Belgium: 1,852,960.00
 : 716,400.00
South Korea: 79,200.00
 : 6,365,530.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 945,600.00
AstraZeneca: 339,600.00
Moderna: 4,000,000.00
Serbia: 4,000,000.00
 : 3,902,903.00
Japan: 3,902,903.00
 : 3,633,353.00
Austria: 3,633,353.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 3,632,335.00
AstraZeneca: 2,432,235.00
Moderna: 878,500.00
Janssen: 16,800.00
Czech Rep.: 3,201,704.00
 : 3,201,704.00
Greece: 3,115,339.00
 : 3,115,339.00
Switzerland: 2,629,843.00
 : 2,629,843.00
Cambodia: 2,411,279.00
 : 2,411,279.00
Australia: 2,254,074.00
 : 2,254,074.00
Singapore: 16,800.00
 : 3,201,704.00
Thailand: 3,201,704.00
Sinovac: 3,115,339.00
AstraZeneca: 3,115,339.00
Nepal: 2,629,843.00
AstraZeneca: 2,629,843.00
Pakistan: 2,411,279.00
 : 2,411,279.00
Denmark: 2,254,074.00
 : 2,254,074.00
Hong Kong SAR, China: 2,007,041.00
Sinovac: 2,007,041.00
Dominican Rep.: 2,000,000.00
 : 2,000,000.00
Ireland: 1,982,185.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 1,982,185.00
AstraZeneca: 1,926,330.00
Moderna: 1,203,930.00
Janssen: 564,000.00
Slovakia: 144,000.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 14,400.00
Gamaleya Research Institute: 2,007,041.00
Moderna: 2,007,041.00
Finland: 2,000,000.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 2,000,000.00
AstraZeneca: 1,982,185.00
Moderna: 1,982,185.00
Uruguay: 1,926,330.00
 : 1,203,930.00
Norway: 564,000.00
 : 144,000.00
Peru: 14,400.00
 : 1,834,409.00
Lithuania: 1,834,409.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 1,700,785.00
AstraZeneca: 1,700,785.00
Moderna: 1,663,307.00
Qatar: 1,663,307.00
 : 1,633,275.00
Kazakhstan: 1,204,005.00
 : 319,252.00
Azerbaijan: 110,018.00
 : 1,603,913.00
Hong Kong: 1,834,409.00
 : 1,834,409.00
Bulgaria: 1,700,785.00
AstraZeneca: 1,700,785.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 1,663,307.00
Moderna: 1,663,307.00
Janssen: 1,633,275.00
Malaysia: 1,204,005.00
 : 319,252.00
Zimbabwe: 110,018.00
Sinovac: 1,603,913.00
Beijing Institute of Biological Products (CNBG): 629,420.00
Mongolia: 169,200.00
 : 14,400.00
Egypt: 1,453,382.00
Beijing Institute of Biological Products (CNBG): 1,453,382.00
AstraZeneca: 1,400,000.00
Bahrain: 1,000,000.00
 : 400,000.00
Nigeria: 1,398,592.00
 : 1,398,592.00
Jordan: 1,350,000.00
Jordan: 629,420.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 169,200.00
Beijing Institute of Biological Products (CNBG): 14,400.00
South Africa: 1,453,382.00
AstraZeneca: 1,453,382.00
Janssen: 1,400,000.00
Iran: 1,000,000.00
 : 400,000.00
Myanmar: 1,398,592.00
 : 1,398,592.00
Ecuador: 1,350,000.00
Ecuador: 1,080,000.00
 : 1,000,000.00
Sri Lanka: 80,000.00
 : 1,068,123.00
Kuwait: 1,068,123.00
 : 1,040,000.00
UK: 1,040,000.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 1,034,338.00
Uzbekistan: 1,034,338.00
Anhui Zhifei Longcom Biopharmaceutical: 1,016,195.00
Costa Rica: 1,016,195.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 1,080,000.00
Croatia: 1,000,000.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 80,000.00
AstraZeneca: 1,068,123.00
Moderna: 1,068,123.00
Janssen: 1,040,000.00
El Salvador: 1,040,000.00
 : 1,034,338.00
Kenya: 1,034,338.00
 : 1,016,195.00
Ghana: 1,016,195.00
 : 457,470.00
Bolivia: 319,200.00
 : 186,128.00
Ukraine: 7,150.00
AstraZeneca: 915,725.00
Sinovac: 915,725.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 853,081.00
Venezuela: 853,081.00
Beijing Institute of Biological Products (CNBG): 849,527.00
Gamaleya Research Institute: 849,527.00
Panama: 848,149.00
Panama: 457,470.00
 : 319,200.00
Slovenia: 186,128.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 7,150.00
AstraZeneca: 915,725.00
Moderna: 915,725.00
Estonia: 853,081.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 853,081.00
AstraZeneca: 849,527.00
Moderna: 849,527.00
Janssen: 848,149.00
 : 687,653.00
Algeria: 671,100.00
Gamaleya Research Institute: 409,500.00
Albania: 184,800.00
```

... and so on.

Comment: Thanks @C.Peck--the solution you proposed does expand the table, but unfortunately, only for the part that is visible. The second major problem I'm having with this scraping challenge is how to scroll all the way down the table so that all rows can be, loaded, then expanded, then scraped.  Right now if you try to grab the row headers, for example, it only returns a handful as the full table only loads when scrolling down.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's tough, but I will try to solve it. I'll let you know if I figure something out. By the way, I improved the code, the current version in my answer is much better than what I had before (but it still only expands the table)

Comment: @anguyen1210 see my updated solution. That should work to scrape all the values (at least from the first two columns) in the table.

Comment: get the following error: 
```wait_for_element(By.XPATH, '//visual-container-modern[11]//button').click()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-229fb8502491>", line 1, in <module>
    wait_for_element(By.XPATH, '//visual-container-modern[11]//button').click()

NameError: name 'By' is not defined```

Comment: @anguyen1210 Oh, you need to add import statement, `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` -- I added the necessary imports in my answer.

Comment: @C.Peck-- Thanks for adding all the import statements.  I ran the your script again.  It gets to the for loop, but strangely, loads and pulls the results from the first 5 rows, but then it just loops through the same 5 rows over and over.  It doesn't actually go down the list, but rather repeats the first 5 (70 times?).

Comment: Weird. As you can see from my output that isn't happening for me. Can you share in your question exactly what code you have just tried? If you copied from my answer I don't.. **think** that should happen

Comment: I copied directly from your latest answer.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, I don't know how to troubleshoot further since we seem to be experiencing very different results from the same script.

Comment: I tried restarting and running the solution you provided, with the same results.  The script just loops over the same countries at the top without scrolling down:  
```China: 275,338,000.00
 : 275,338,000.00
USA: 264,505,725.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 134,063,475.00
Moderna: 112,801,100.00
Janssen: 17,641,150.00
India: 154,211,511.00
 : 154,211,511.00
Indonesia: 60,000,000.00
Sinovac: 60,000,000.00
Brazil: 44,100,000.00
China: 275,338,000.00
 : 275,338,000.00
USA: 264,505,725.00
Pfizer/BioNTech: 134,063,475.00
Moderna: 112,801,100.00
``` ... and so on

Comment: The only difference between how we are running the tests is how to initialize chromedriver. I can't imagine that would matter for this.... I am confused, but maybe I will figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I guess, for some reason, the action to induce scrolling is not working for you.

Comment: thanks @C.Peck--the solution you proposed i take for scrap anothe power bi report and the scrolls actions were a nightmere but know is a yesterday problem